# How to serialize mutiple querysets in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models that area related to each other. One represents a project and the other one represents the field/area that the project bnelongs to.

I have a view that looks like this:

```
class ProjetosArea(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = ProjetosPreviaSerializer
    pagination_class = ProjectPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        area_id = self.kwargs['id']

        area = AreaConhecimento.objects.get(id=area_id)
        projetos = Projeto.objects.filter(area_conhecimento=area_id)

        queryset =  [area, projetos]

        return queryset
```

I want to write a serializer for this view that looks like this:

```
{
   "area": {---fields of the area---},
   "projects": [---The projects that belongs to that area---]
}
```

How would write a serializer for this? The queryset is a list with the area and the projects belonging to that area

Comment: May you share the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `get_queryset` doesn't look right. The idea is to return a single queryset there to perform permissions check etc in there. You should not return two resources like that.

Although if you need it - the code is just a tool. Do with it whatever you need.

---

I'd suggest to keep `get_queryset` as it is and overwrite `list` method instead as that's what you really want to do. Because you are returning two resources, it needs to know how to handle them.

From example I deduct that `area_conhecimento` is area `pk`. So something like that should work.

```
class ProjetosArea(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'area_conhecimento'
    serializer_class = ProjetosAreaSerializer
    pagination_class = ProjectPagination

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        area = qs.first().area_conhecimento

        # you will have to adjust it for pagination
        serializer = self.get_serializer({
            'projects': qs,
            'area': area
        })
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And just the serializers are as simple as it gets.

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class AreaConhecimentoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AreaConhecimento
        fields = '__all__'


class ProjetoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Projeto
        fields = '__all__'


class ProjetosAreaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    area = AreaConhecimentoSerializer(read_only=True)
    projects = ProjetoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

---

But your real problem is that you actually want to get area and its projects. So just do it. You said it yourself `The projects that belongs to that area`.

```
class AreaRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = AreaSerializer
    pagination_class = AreaPagination


class ProjetoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Projeto
        fields = '__all__'
        

class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projeto = ProjetoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = AreaConhecimento
        fields = '__all__'
```

and it will return

```
{
   "area": {
        "projects": [---The projects that belongs to that area---],
         ---fields of the area---
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I didn't do it that way, but your answer helped me realize the solution!